# Python Subprocess write data to pipe

Tags: python

example:

```
from subprocess import *
proc = Popen(['cat','-'], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
msg = 'Through STDIN TO STDOUT' 
stdout_value = proc.communicate(msg)[0] 
print 'stdout:', stdout_value
```

output :
  stdout: Through STDIN TO STDOUT

> in this example I have passed the msg string to the called
>   program(cat -) as stdin,
>       what if the called program was the (passwd) command, is it possible to pass two stdin([password value] and [verification password value]) to it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to pass two lines of input:

```
msg = 'line1\nline2\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Assuming `passwd` reads from standard input, you would simply write two lines to `proc`'s standard input, either by setting `msg` to something like `mypass\nmypass\n`, or simply making two calls to `proc.communicate`. However, for security reasons `passwd` reads directly from the terminal, unless you *specifically* tell it to read from standard input with `passwd --stdin` (where available).

Comment: On what system does `passwd` read from `/dev/tty`? On my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system, it reads from stdin.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting the need for the `--stdin` option that `passwd` takes on the Scientific Linux box I'm looking at. It does seem to read from standard input by default, based on the result of `passwd < /dev/null`.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, I am geniunely curious about differences between systems.

Comment: No, I made an unwarranted assumption based on the existence of `--stdin` (and by analogy to `sudo` or `ssh`--something reads directly from the terminal, I'm pretty sure). I'm not sure what context requires `--stdin`.